Error Opening Emulator, storing crashdata in emu-crash-34.1.20.db file
I am new to mobile app development and I have been trying to create my first flutter app on android studio but for some reason i can't connect my project to the virtual device that i created.
This is what i have in the flutter device selection
this is the error that i get
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\FARAH\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 19208 INFO | Android emulator version 34.1.20.0 (build_id 11610631) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\src\flutter\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\ INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: d0a6:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 (2x) ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\FARAH\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 24936 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | Increasing RAM size to 3072MB INFO | IPv4 server found: 1.1.1.1 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 787b:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 787b:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 9081:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 9081:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: a887:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: a887:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 1890:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 1890:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 7898:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: b0a0:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: b0a0:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: d0a6:c4e5:6101:0:d075:c4e5:6101:0
I don't know if this caused the problem but I was initially trying to setup flutter on vscode so I changed some of the sdk paths on my laptop. I hope you can help, thank you.
I tried deleting the emu-crash-34.1.20.db file,
i also saw this solution (Open your Task Manager and end Android Studio
Also, end adb.exe & emulator.exe and qemu-system-x86_64.exe
Go to, C:\Users"YOUR_USER".android\avd, here you can find "ini" file and folder for your emulator device. delete both of them.) and tried it but nothing happened.
and neither installing the  33.1.24 emulator version nor connecting android studio to an androis smart phone worked

This is intended as a suggestion rather than a solution, hence it's formatted as a comment. Please consider the following steps, which do not need to be completed in order:
Restart your laptop/PC.
Terminate any running emulators and processes.
Delete and reconfigure your Android Virtual Device (AVD).
Execute the flutter doctor command to diagnose issues.

Update:
The only solution that worked for me was to run the command
(flutter config --android-sdk pathToYourSDK) in the terminal. (Note that you need to exchange the pathToYourSDK with your actual path to SDK that you can get from tools --> SDK Manager).
Also make sure that the android sdk is selected from the (Project settings --> Project Structure).

Use a different AVD: Instead of trying to run multiple instances of the same AVD, create a new AVD and try running your Flutter app on that and if still the issue presist then try to reinstall android studio and flutter
